# Why does this code for adding a driver cause Blender 2.83 to hard crash?

Tags: python, drivers

This code is run as part of a loop which iterates over selected objects. When I remove this block of code, the rest runs fine, but if I include this block it causes a hard crash.
trb_n is a shader node and w_plane is an object. Both are established earlier in the code.

```
fcurve = trb_n.inputs['Water Origin'].driver_add('default_value')
driver = fcurve.driver
driver.type = 'SCRIPTED'
var = driver.variables.new()
var.name = "zpos"
targ = var.targets[0]
targ.id_type = 'OBJECT'
targ.id = w_plane
targ.data_path = 'location[2]'
driver.expression = var.name
```

Comment: If you [run Blender from the command line](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/launch/index.html), you might see an error message leading to the crash (and you can add print statements in your code to monitor your script progression)